# How to explain why we can’t factor $x^n + y^n$ for all natural numbers n, to 13 year olds?

Tags: middle-school

Michael Spivak, *Calculus* (4th edn 2008), p 13.  I know this monograph is aimed at undergraduates (not middle schoolers), but this kind of multiple-part question resurfaces on standardized tests for 13 year olds (henceforth y.o.).

> 1. Prove the following:

> (v) $x^n - y^n = (x - y)(x^{n - 1} + x^{n - 2}y + \cdots + xy^{n - 2} + y{^n - 1}).$
> (vi) $x^3 + y^3 = (x + y)(x^ 2- xy + y^2)$. (There is a particularly easy way to do this, using (iv), and it will show you how to find a factorization for $x^n + y^n$ $\color{peru}{\; whenever  \; n \; is \; odd}.$)

Ibid, p 619.

> (vi) Replace $y$ by $-y$ in (iv).

Answers that use [Cyclotomic Polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3684657), [Modular Arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3860053), [Complex Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3860075) are too Delphic for 13 y.o.!

[Brian M. Scott](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12042/brian-m-scott)’s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3860047) is TOO gruff and sketchy for 13 y.o. to fathom. To wit, 13 y.o. know that $(a + b)[a^{n – 1} – a^{n – 2}b + . . . + \color{mediumspringgreen}{+} ab^{n – 2} \color{red}{-} b^{n – 1}] \equiv a^n – b^n$. But this doesn’t answer their question!   How can 13 y.o. intuit why they can't factor out $(x + y)$ from $x^n + y^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Maybe start with $y=1$ and show that:  $\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}$ is not a polynomial.  Do this by examining what happens as $x \to -1$.

Comment: Do you mean "for all *natural numbers* $n$"?

Comment: "*How do we know that $c$ can't exist, such that $(x+y)c=x^n+y^n$?*" with $n,x,y\in\mathbb R$. Try $c=1$, $n=1$.

Comment: 3 hours old, and already 3 answers posted as comments! Post answers as answers instead, so they can be edited, voted on, and commented on.

Comment: @Raciquel Have you voted to close it?

Comment: "this kind of multiple-part question resurfaces on standardized tests for 13 year olds" Really? That does not seem at all reasonable.

Comment: That's a very mathematically elite group of $13$ year olds. I'm guessing an Asian country, probably China. I would expect this sort of question to be aimed at $16-17$ year olds or older, here in the UK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the factor theorem, unless you think it’s also too “Delphic” for your students. The factor theorem tells us that a polynomial $p(x)$ has a factor $(x-r)$ if and only if $p(r)=0$. Equivalently, $p(x)$ has a factor $(x-r)$ if and only if $r$ is a root of $p(x)$.

Let’s consider the polynomial defined as $p(x) = x^n + a^n$, where $a$ is non-zero. It has a factor $(x+a)$ if and only if $p(-a)=0$. But $$p(-a)=(-a)^n+a^n=
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{ if $n$ is odd,} \\
2a^n &\text{if $n$ is even,}
\end{cases}$$
therefore $(x+a)$ is a factor of $x^n+a^n$ if and only if $n$ is odd.

Furthermore, if $n$ is even, $x^n+a^n$ has no linear factors as a polynomial over the real numbers. This is because the roots of $x^n+a^n$ are the solutions to the equation $x^n=-a^n$. This equation has no real solutions.

Answer (score 3):

The question is framed very oddly, so I'm not really sure what you're looking for.

If the student understands that p(x) being factorable means that p(x)=0 has roots when any linear factor equals 0, then you can use desmos to graph y=^n + a^n. For all real nonzero values of a and even values of n, this does not cross the x-axis, hence there are no linear factors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe show them $x^2+y^2$ as an example?  It is unfactorable. Let them try.

If anything this is a lor easier than proving general quintic has no formula, which you can only assert to students not prove.

Comment: For $x^2+y^2$ I would add the following: if it were factorable, the set of solutions of $x^2+y^2 = 0$ would include a line, but it doesn't. This argument should be understandable to younger students.